# How to fire component methods not bound to rendered children elements?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing snapshot tests for some React components that make server requests, and am having trouble figuring out a sensible way to test them. Given the following example:

```
class FetchingComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      serverError: null;
    }
  }

  doServerOperation = () => {
    makeServerRequest()
    .then((result) => console.log('Great!'))
    .catch((error) => this.onRequestFailure(error));
  }

  onRequestFailure = (error) => {
    this.setState({serverError: error});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.doServerOperation}/>
        { this.state.serverError && <div>{this.state.serverError}</div> }
        </div>
      )
    }

}
```

I would like to test that `onRequestFailure` renders the expected output in a snapshot. However, as far as I can tell there’s no way for me to manually trigger `onRequestFailure` — the tree given to me from `component.toJSON()` only lets me trigger `doServerOperation`, which is bound to the child button’s `onClick` attribute.

- Is there any way to trigger component methods that are not bound to any of its rendered children?
- Is there some way to mock component functions bound to children, so that I could avoid the hassle of mocking something like Relay, and instead have it fire my `onRequestFailure` method right away?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the trick I was missing was to use `getInstance()` on the component created by `renderer.create()`!